# Small open sets around a point intersecting pieces of orbits

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, approximation-theory

Let $T$ be an ergodic rotation on a compact Abelian group. Can one always find a point $x_0$ and a decreasing sequence of open sets $O_n \searrow \{x_0\}$ such that for every $n$ there exists $K \geq 0$ such that $O_n \cap {\bigl\{T^k(x)\bigr\}}_{k=0}^K \neq \varnothing$ for almost every $x$ ?

For an ergodic rotation on a circle, there is known cut-and-stack procedure related to the continuous fraction expansion of the irrational rotation number. If one takes $O_n$ to be the basis of the procedure, I think that the $O_n$ would fulfill the condition if $O_n \searrow \{x_0\}$. Is it true ?

Comment: Any ergodic rotation on a compact Abelian group is minimal (every orbit is dense). It follows (by compactness) that for every open set $O$, there exists a $K$ such that for every $x$, at least one of $x$, $Tx$, ..., $T^{K-1}x$ lies in $O$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Thank you. I do not daily practice mathematics. It is possible your claim was obvious for me when I was a student, but nowadays I don't see how compactness implies that. Please do you have a hint ?

Comment: Oh wait, I was just waking up. I remember the Borel-Lebesgue property now, and I think I get your point. Mayve I should delete this elementary question. But just by curiosity, I would still like to know the answer of my second question, about the rotation.

Comment: Proof of (every orbit dense) implies (every orbit uniformly dense) by the contrapositive: suppose $O$ is open and there exist arbitrarily long orbit segments: $(T^ix_n)_{-n\le i\le n}$ that never hit $O$. Then take a subsequential limit of the $x_n$. The orbit of this point never hits $O$. In particular for the specific $O_n$ you mention coming from the CF algorithm, the conclusion certainly holds.

Comment: Thank you for your help @AnthonyQuas. I have just started to learn about minimality and various relations with ergodicity but I am still a bit overwhelmed by the amount of results.